# Virtual Box failed to open a session. Exit code 1073741819

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, rhel

I'm trying to install a VM with RHEL7 using Virtual Box. This question has appeared several times before but no answer is definitive or even correct. I have tried all the suggestions on other posts.

The VM doesn't boot after simply going through the installation process with Virtual Box. The error message is:

`Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}`

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE!

The problem was fixed by uninstalling Virtual Box and reinstalling version 4.3.12. For some reason, this is the latest version that doesn't show the error.